# How to mock a bean like Mockito with okhttp MockWebServer

Tags: spring, mockito, okhttp, mockwebserver

I am trying to use OkHttp MockWebServer to mock few API calls I use. Currently I use Mockito. I am trying to find out whether I can use MockWebServer as Its way simpler to use. I have a mock bean created with Mockito as below:

```
@MockBean
RestService restService;
```

and then I use Mockito's when() to track a method call in the mock bean and return an response.

```
Mockito.doReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.OK)).
            when(restService).callUrl(
            eq(url),
            any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class),
            any(Class.class)
    );
```

Is there a way I can replicate a similar functionality using OkHttp MockWebServer?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?